# Online novel: boy has two lives, one when he is awake and another when he sleeps

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a novel on [Royal Road](https://www.royalroad.com/welcome) where there's a normal guy who awakens on a futuristic Earth where people have abilities. His gets put on 'D' grade or similar. His friend gets to go to some islands where he learns about his powers (he is something like a 'B' rank or higher).

The ability of the main character means that he goes to another world when he's asleep, but one night is like weeks in the dream world. The dream world is a fantasy world but he lives out both lives.

He has a crush in his normal life and goes to some elite school for people who didn't make it into the really special school.

He loves running in the main world and loses a leg because he gets hit by a car.

He is also the heir to an assassin family in the dream/fantasy world.

Comment: Welcome to SE, thank you for including a good level of detail! do you happen to remember anything to do with the length of the novel, when you read it (or when it was released) or a splash art?

Answer (score 2):

*Dreams Come True* (2018) by Parky.

From [RoyalRoad](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/22356/dreams-come-true):

> In a futuristic world of superheroes and supervillains, **the ability to dream of another world** doesn’t seem that applicable nor useful. But for **Demund, who has recently sent off his best friend to the superhero training grounds—the Preliminary Islands—** it was nothing but life-changing. For him, a rejuvenating vacation to a world of magic is now only a good night’s rest away.
>
> As Demund explores his new world, reality around him begins to change. How will he manage to balance their existences together?

Demund and his friend are ranked D+ and B+, respectively ([chapter 1.1](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/22356/dreams-come-true/chapter/319793/11)):

> **“B+? not bad. You’ll definitely pass the Selection with that score.”**
>
> “It’ll satisfy my parents well enough. So, what did you get?”
>
> Jothan carefully put his evaluation sheet back into his packet. Demund’s packet was on his desk, still unopened with the glue intact on the lid. Demund stared at it. He predicted that he would not make the Selection, but still had a faint hope from what the examiners had told him. Maybe…just maybe his score was high enough. **He might be able to join his friend on the Islands after all.** Or his wishes were unanswered and he’d stay in his everyday, bland life just like the majority of the population.
>
> “You really want to see? It’s probably much lower than yours.”
>
> “But I want to know whether you’ll go to the Selection with me or not.”
>
> [...] Demund reached his fingers inside, pinched the paper, and lifted it up for Jothan and himself to see. To their surprise, they found a rather disappointing score.
>
> **“A D+.”**

Demund loses a leg to a car accident ([chapter 4.3](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/22356/dreams-come-true/chapter/348053/43)):

> **“What’s wrong with your leg?” asked a student** while Demund was packing his things. His arms were crossed, and he had a frown on his face—his lips were pursed. “Got into an accident?”
>
> Demund looked up from his bag and stared directly into the student’s eyes.
>
> **“It got run over by a car. They had to amputate it,”** he said with a smile.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi other world dreams site:royalroad.com`.